# How do I create a permalink structure with 2 taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I would like to create permalink to a search for a custom post type that has 2 taxonomies in it. Here are a few appropriate examples:

```
/root/%taxonomyA%/%taxonomyB%
/root/%taxonomyA%/taxonomyB/%taxonomyB%
```

Taxonomy B can be inside any number of Taxonomy As.

I already have something for this structure that works great:

```
/root/%taxonomyA%/%customPostType%
```

Is this possible? I prefer the 1st example, but I would be fine with the 2nd.

I did attempt to put this rewrite rule in, but I don't get the matches I expect in the rewrite inspector.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^root/([^/]+)/taxonomyB/([^/]+)',
    'index.php?post_type=customPostType&taxonomyA=$matches[1]&taxonomyB=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

When I put in `root/A/taxonomyB/B` the inspector, it comes up as `attachment: B`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do. Every taxonomy is independent and the terms can't be shared between them. The only way I know to do a search with 2 parameters: taxonomy A term and taxonomy B term, and pass it to a `WP Query` along with the `custom post type`.